# Tracert: Why would an IP address have letters in it?

Tags: command-prompt

I am doing homework for my networking class (I am pretty new to it, so bear with me..), and the assignment is to do the `tracert google.com` command, but why would the hops have an IP showing stuff like `2607:f8b0:4009:808:200e`.

What is it called when they mask the IP, and why would they do it?

Answer (score 2):

IP address could be in V4, or V6.  Both of them are a sequence of numbers which could be represented as hexadecimal.  Those are not letters, but 'numbers' in the 0-9A-F number system.

Comment: Thank you, shortly after posting this i went through my book a 3rd time and saw that, the hexidecimal is how IPv6 shows up with tracert.